# pexpect capturing muliple commands output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand pexpect module and trying to print multiple commands output. but it's not giving the result as expected.

```
import pexpect
def main():
        child = pexpect.spawn('sudo su - bhreddy1')
        child.expect('bhreddy1')
        child.sendline('df -h')
        child.expect('bhreddy1')
        print('\nrunning df -h commnd' )
        print(child.before.decode())
        print('\ncompleted df -h commnd' )
        child.sendline('ls')
        child.expect('bhreddy1')
        child.sendline('exit')
        print('\nrunning ls commnd' )
        print(child.before.decode())
        print('\ncompleted ls commnd' )
        child.interact()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Expected output:

```
running df -h commnd
@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            476M     0  476M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/sda1       218G  1.9G  205G   1% /
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       923M   59M  802M   7% /boot
/dev/sda4       266G  306M  252G   1% /home
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1001

completed df -h commnd

running ls commnd
bhr
completed ls commnd
```

Actual result:

```
running df -h commnd
@ubuntu: ~

completed df -h commnd

running ls commnd
@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            476M     0  476M   0% /dev
tmpfs           100M   11M   89M  11% /run
/dev/sda1       218G  1.9G  205G   1% /
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       923M   59M  802M   7% /boot
/dev/sda4       266G  306M  252G   1% /home
tmpfs           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/1001


completed ls commnd
@ubuntu: ~bhreddy1@ubuntu:~$ ls
bhr
bhreddy1@ubuntu:~$ exit
logout
```

someone please suggest how to collect multiple commands ouptut. Do we have any option to register only command output to variable and prints that variable at the end.

Comment: for pexpect line `@ubuntu: ...` is also output from command. It doesn't treat your commands as separated programs. For pexpect you run 'sudo su - bhreddy1' and it gives you all outputs from this command.

Comment: maybe you should use `expect('bhreddy1@ubuntu:.*')` with `.*` to get full line - and this should remove also `@ubuntu:` from output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `@ubuntu: ~`, etc. from output then you sould use `.*` in `expect()` to get full line - and this should remove it from output

```
        child.expect('bhreddy1@ubuntu:.*')
```

---

```
import pexpect

def main():
        child = pexpect.spawn('sudo su - bhreddy1')
        child.expect('bhreddy1@ubuntu:.*')

        child.sendline('df -h')
        child.expect('bhreddy1@ubuntu:.*')

        print('\nrunning df -h commnd' )
        print(child.before.decode())
        print('\ncompleted df -h commnd' )

        child.sendline('ls')
        child.expect('bhreddy1@ubuntu:.*')

        print('\nrunning ls commnd' )
        print(child.before.decode())
        print('\ncompleted ls commnd' )

        child.sendline('exit')

        child.interact()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

And if you need output in variable then simply use `=` or `+=` to join strings.

You may have to add also `\n` after every text because normally `print()` adds `\n` at the end.

```
result = ""

# ... code ...

result += '\nrunning df -h commnd\n'
result += child.before.decode() + '\n'
result += '\ncompleted df -h commnd\n'

# ... code ...

result += '\nrunning ls commnd\n'
result += child.before.decode() + '\n'
result += '\ncompleted ls commnd\n'

# ... code ...

print(result)
```

You can also keep it as a list and later convert all to one string and add `\n` using `"\n".join(list)`.

```
result = []

# ... code ...

result.append('\nrunning df -h commnd')
result.append(child.before.decode())
result.append('\ncompleted df -h commnd')

# ... code ...

result.append('\nrunning ls commnd')
result.append(child.before.decode())
result.append('\ncompleted ls commnd')

# ... code ...

text = "\n".join(result)

print(text)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to see some results then maybe use `child.before` without `print()`

```
    child.sendline('exit')
    child.expect('exit')
    child.expect('exit')   # on my system it displays `exit` two times so I need `expect` two times
    child.before.before()  # get output but don't `print()`
```

---

**BTW:**

You repeate some code so you could create function:

```py
import pexpect

def run(child, cmd):
    child.sendline(cmd)
    child.expect('bhreddy1@ubuntu:.*')

    print(f'\nrunning {cmd} commnd' )
    print(child.before.decode())
    print(f'\ncompleted {cmd} commnd' )
    
def main():
    child = pexpect.spawn('sudo su - bhreddy1')
    child.expect('bhreddy1@ubuntu:.*')

    run('df -h')
    
    run('ls')

    child.sendline('exit')
    child.expect('exit')
    child.expect('exit')   # it can display `exit` two times
    child.before.decode()  # get output without `print()`
    
    child.interact()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I am able to get ouptut properly.  but output contains command which executed i.e.., `df -h , ls` and after statement `completed ls command` output shows `exit logout` statements. how to skip `df -h, ls and exit,  logout` statements.

Comment: If you use `expect` with `.*` then it should skip FULL line so it should skip also `df -h, ls`. As for `exit`, `logout` - maybe you should send `exit` after last `child.before.decode()` OR maybe you shouldn't display last `child.before.decode()`